# How can I add more one abstract and one more keywords "section" to the ACM template

Tags: acm, acmart

I'm writing an article for a conference in Brazil that uses the latex template from ACM format (ACM Conference Proceedings - New Master Template) and I wanted to know how can I add one more abstract and one more keywords "section"?

As I am writing for a Brazilian conference I must have "Resumo" (an abstract in Portuguese) and "Palavras-chave" (the keywords in Portuguese).

I tried to create them only using \begin{resumo} or \begin{palavrasChaves}, but it says that:

Environment resumo undefined

So I tried to modify the acmart.cls, to create these two sections ("Resumo" and "Palavras-chave"), but I couldn't make any progress...

I've also tried to find it in the acmart.pdf, but I couldn't find how to create new "sections".

The ACM template has the following instructions:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\title{SIG Proceedings Paper in LaTeX Format}

\begin{abstract}
This paper provides a sample of ACM SIG Proceedings.
\end{abstract}

\keywords{ACM proceedings, \LaTeX}

 % Right Here I need the abstract in portuguese ("Resumo") and 
 % afterwards I need the keywords in portuguese ("Palavras-chave").

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

I have sent an e-mail to acm support but they haven't answered yet, but as it is quite urgent could you help me with that?

P.S: I am working with the Overleaf template.

[acm-conference-proceedings-new-master-template - Overleaf](https://pt.overleaf.com/latex/templates/acm-conference-proceedings-new-master-template/pnrfvrrdbfwt)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

ACM answered me:

If you want to add another Abstract and Keywords section in other languages in your article you must add the following instructions:

```
    \makeatletter
    
   \def\portkeywords#1{\g@addto@macro\@keywords{\endgraf\bigskip{\bfseries\Large\noindent PALAVRAS-CHAVE}\endgraf\noindent#1}}%
    
    \newenvironment{otherlangabstract}{\Collect@Body\@saveaotherbstract}{}
    
    \long\def\@saveaotherbstract#1{\g@addto@macro\@abstract{\endgraf\bigskip{\bfseries\Large\noindent RESUMO}\endgraf\noindent\ignorespaces#1}}
    
    \@saveaotherbstract{}
    
    \makeatother
```

Just create both and you are ready to go...

```
\begin{otherlangabstract}
 Resumo em português.
\end{otherlangabstract}

\portkeywords{Procedimentos ACM}
```

**UPDATE: Change Keywords to Palavras-Chaves**

If the other way doesn't work anymore, you can try this:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\@specialsection{Keywords}}{\@specialsection{Palavras-Chave}}{}{}
\makeatother

\keywords{another, way, to, change, keywords}
```